# At-Rule exceptions in Stylelint for the opening brace newline?

Tags: css, stylelint

I am working on the rules in my .stylelintrc .  The objective is to have single line CSS, so 'block-opening-brace-newline-after' is set to 'never-multi-line'.  The exception that I would like is for at-rules.  Ideally, the selectors after the at-rule brace would go to the next line.  There aren't any "except" options listed for the [block-opening-brace-newline-after](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/block-opening-brace-newline-before) rule.  Any ideas?

for example, this:

```
.container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        padding: 5px;
        margin: 0
    }
}
```

Would ideally become:

```
.container { padding: 0; margin: 5px }
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container { padding: 5px; margin: 0 }}
```

so the newline after the opening brace is handled differently for at-rules.

Comment: Can you provide code examples to illustrate what you mean, please?

Comment: @jeddy3 good call.  Just updated with an example.

Comment: It's not currently possible to enforce that convention. However, options can be added to the rules to make it possible. I suggest raising a feature request in the stylelint issue tracker.